# mod_wsgi (3.4-14) / Apache 2.4.12 / Red Hat (6.7) / Django 1.8.2 hanging under load

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

I have a problem with `mod_wsgi (3.4-14)` / `Apache 2.4.12` / `cx_oracle 5.2` / `Oracle 12` / `Django 1.8.2` hanging under bigger load.
The configuration was used for the last several month in dev  / testing.

Now when deployed to production environment `Apache` hangs after couple of minutes under bigger load (it works fine with small or moderate load).

I have a cluster of 3 `Django/Apache/mod_wsgi` servers and when this problems happens each server stops responding (one by one) within 5 - 15 minutes.

Here is my configuration

I am using `Python 3.3` and `Apache 2.4.12` and `mod_wsgi-3.4-14` from `Red Hat (6.7)` Software Collection

Apache Virtual Host

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
... 
        WSGIDaemonProcess app.prod processes=2 threads=25 display-name=%{GROUP} user=MY_USER python-path=MY_PATH
        WSGIProcessGroup app.prod
        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/hosts/app/app/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache version

```
    Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Red Hat)
    Server built:   Aug 11 2015 08:12:59
    Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:41
    Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
    Compiled using: APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
    Architecture:   64-bit
    Server MPM:     worker
      threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
        forked:     yes (variable process count)
    Server compiled with....
     -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
     -D APR_HAS_MMAP
     -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
     -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
     -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
     -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
     -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
     -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
     -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
     -D HTTPD_ROOT="/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd"
     -D SUEXEC_BIN="/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/suexec"
     -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
     -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
     -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
     -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
     -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

`python33-mod_wsgi-3.4-14.el6.x86_64`

Django db configuration

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'webuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'webpassword',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': None,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'threaded': True,
        },
    },
```

```
    #0  0x00007f047ff099b0 in sem_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
    #1  0x00007f0474b4c6d8 in PyThread_acquire_lock_timed () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #2  0x00007f0474b2cab5 in _PyImport_AcquireLock () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #3  0x00007f0474b2cf49 in PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #4  0x00007f0474b10f8f in ?? () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #5  0x00007f0474b1baa4 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #6  0x00007f0474b1b0f9 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #7  0x00007f0474b1c457 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #8  0x00007f0474b1aead in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #9  0x00007f0474b1b0f9 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #10 0x00007f0474b1b0f9 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #11 0x00007f0474b1b0f9 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #12 0x00007f0474b1b0f9 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #13 0x00007f0474b1b0f9 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #14 0x00007f0474b1b0f9 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #15 0x00007f0474b1c457 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #16 0x00007f0474a90842 in ?? () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #17 0x00007f0474a69fd6 in PyObject_Call () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #18 0x00007f0474b11763 in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords () from /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
    #19 0x00007f0474e8f6ac in ?? () from /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/modules/mod_python33-wsgi.so
    #20 0x00007f0474e93f8b in ?? () from /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/modules/mod_python33-wsgi.so
    #21 0x00007f0474e976c8 in ?? () from /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/modules/mod_python33-wsgi.so
    #22 0x00007f047ff03a51 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
    #23 0x00007f047fc509ad in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

If I reduce the number of `mod_wsgi` then the problem goes away but the performance is not acceptable.

`WSGIDaemonProcess app.prod processes=4 threads=1 display-name=%{GROUP} user=MY_USER python-path=MY_PATH`

Could anybody suggest what could be the cause or how could I debug it please?

[More details on mod_wsgi mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/99oBs1FucSw)

Comment: Does it hang with `threads=1`, or is it the stable but slow configuration?

Comment: Yes is still hangs with threads=1. Just it takes longer to hang

Answer (score 0):

According to me, getting more ram can help. I used to ran multiple django sites on my server and apache usually stops working now and then. It used to work correctly when I restart, but again goes down after some time. 
Check how much ram is left in your server under load : `free -m`. The server should have around `100-200mb` of free ram to make apache work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have workaround with following mod_wsgi configuration

```
processes=12 threads=1 inactivity-timeout=300 maximum-requests=1000
```

and it does addresses the problem.

But there is a plan to fix the core issue.